# Struggling to visualise conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

[image]

I'm really struggling to visualise why certain conformal mappings give me these new geometries. In particular, I'm struggling to understand the figure I attached above: the author of the figure claims that the following mapping was used:
$$w=\log z$$

I tried to understand this by letting $z=re^{i\theta}$ and so $w=\log r + j\theta$. This gives me for $w=u+jv$ that $u=\log r$ and $\theta = v$. Now how do I go from the $w$-plane to the $z$-plane?

For the left boundary on the $w$ plane, I have $u=0$, which gives me $r=1$, or a unit circle. But since $v\in[0,\pi]$, I only get a half unit circle centred at the origin. I'm guessing this corresponds to the "Insulation" label in the $z$-diagram.

For the bottom boundary, I have $v=0$ and so $\theta=0$, meaning I'm somewhere on the positive axis. Since $u\in[0,-\infty]$, I'm not sure what to do now since $u=\log r$. What am I missing?

Comment: How is the right most vertical a circle of zero radius? Wouldn't I be solving $\log r = 0$ such that I get a (half) unit circle?

Comment: Apologies, I'm still not understanding correctly. Yes, the right-most vertical part is pure imaginary so that means $u=0$ right? Since $u=\log r$, I must have $r=1$ so then I must be getting $e^{jt}$ where $t\in[0,\pi]$

Comment: Sorry, I had it backwards in my head when I explained it. Let me redo that comment oriented correctly:

Comment: Each vertical line in the strip is mapped to a circle in the disk. The right most vertical is sent to the unit circle, while the left most vertical is sent to small inner circle (the inner "insulation"). Everything else smoothly interpolates between. By the way the bending occurs, it takes a vertical line and "bends" it into a circle, with the top of the line being the point on the positive real axis and the bottom of the line being the point on the negative real axis. Think of turning the vertical line sideways and "stretching" the middle of it upwards

Comment: So to answer your question, yes: the right boundary of the strip maps to the boundary of the disk, namely the unit circle. As we go left in the strip our real part is getting more negative, so the function $e^z$ will get smaller in absolute value (since $e^{-x}$ decreases as $x$ increases) so we get smaller circles

Comment: Where did you get $u\in[0,-\infty]$ from? (And what does $[0,-\infty]$ mean? Is it a typo?) Clearly, $u$ is bounded below by the left insulation wall in the $w$ plane.